# Loop through two variables in multidimensional array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, multidimensional-array, resampling

I have a three-dimensional array (hyperspectral image) and I would like to resample for each element of the two first dimensions (each pixel) the third dimension (wavelength).

I have been trying a nested for loop without success and I think i am understanding wrongly the concept. Here what I am trying:

```
    T_Ire = zeros(size(I)); % initialize array

for i = 1:numel(I(:,1,1))
    for t = 1:numel(I(1,:,1))

   step=squeeze(I(i,t,:));
   step=double(step);
   step=step';
   step=resample(step',2,3);
   T_Ire(i,t,:)=step;

    end
end
```

I is the 3D array (hyperspectral image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. When you call `step=resample(step',2,3);`, your array will be two thirds the size it was. Then, when you try to put it back on the cubic matrix, it will not fit because it has fewer elements. You could solve that by initializing `T_Ire` with the appropriate size.

Like this:

```
T_Ire = zeros(size(I, 1), size(I, 2), size(I, 3) * 2 / 3);
```

2. When you take the array `I(i,t,:)`, it's size will be `1x1xN` (where `N` = the size of the third dimension). But when you call `step=squeeze(I(i,t,:));`, now it is `Nx1`. To add it back, you should call [permute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) or [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to resize it back to `1x1xN`.

Using [permute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
T_Ire(i,t,:) = permute(step, [3 2 1]);
```

Using [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
T_Ire(i,t,:) = reshape(step, [1 1 numel(step)]);
```